# Inverse matrix elements: is it possible to find some pattern?

Tags: matrices, inverse

I am studying lower triangular matrix with elements:

$$ M_{i,j}=(-1)^j \frac{i!}{(i-j)!} F_{i-j} ,~ i\geq j,~ i,j=0,1,2,\dots$$

where $F_n$ are constants. It can be easily recursively inverted. However I wish to find an explicit formula depending on row/column number. It turns out that all columns of $M^{-1}$ can be expressed as function of the first column (index zero). However, this column has complicated structure where some patterns can be observed, but others I am unable to find. Here are two equivalent forms of the first column $M^{-1}_{i,0}$:

[columnZero_v1](http://147.213.122.82/~andrej/Hzz2587Qj/firstColumn_v1.png)

[columnZeto_v2](http://147.213.122.82/~andrej/Hzz2587Qj/firstColumn_v2.png)

This is presumably a very hard question... but maybe I am lucky and somebody has an idea.